# Choosing a table to save to based on drop down choice

Tags: php, mysql

I have 12 locations that I'm trying to figure out if I should create 12 tables (1 for each community) to save to or 1 table, add the location as a column, and throw everything in it and just get the data I need based on the location row?

```
CREATE TABLE `location1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `newsTitle` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `introParagraph` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `newsLink` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `downloadLink` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `file` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

Comment: It probably really depends on your use cases. Do you think each community will always need the same exact columns of data?

Comment: You can use this for reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9774715/mysql-multiple-tables-or-one-table-with-many-columns based on your design.

Comment: @MikeBrant the table will hold data for a newsletter and will be the same type of data each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single table for your requirement.
When you need to save the data for locations which is different you can overcome this situation by using php [serialize()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.unserialize.php). When you get data you can do whatever you want after unserializing. You can use the field as text.

```
CREATE TABLE `location` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `location_data` text(32565) NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

Here is how you can save data in table

```
$location       =   'Location A';
$location_data  =   array('langitude' => 32.123 , 'longitude' => 87.3123 , 'status' => 'active');

$serialized =   serialize($location_data);
$query  =   "INSERT INTO location (location , location_data) VALUES ('$location','$serialized')";
mysqli_query($query);

$location       =   'Location B';
$location_data  =   array('test1' => 123 , 'test2' => 321); 

$serialized =   serialize($location_data);
$query  =   "INSERT INTO location (location , location_data) VALUES ('$location','$serialized')";
mysqli_query($query);
```

And when you get result

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM location WHERE id=1";
$rs = mysqli_query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
$location_data = unserialize($row['location_data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 table.  If the only difference is which community the row belongs to, then definitely 1 table.  If there will be other differences, then depends on use as Mike said.